# creating a class name from a string, integer and function parameter in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, concatenation

```js
function imageNext(Class) {

  for (i = 1; i < 7; i++) {
    document.querySelector(Class + "image" + i).style.display = "none";
    document.querySelector(Class + "image" + (i + 1)).style.display = "block";
  }
  if (i > 7) {
    document.querySelector(Class + "image1").style.display = "block";
  }

}

function imagePrev(Class) {
  for (i = 1; i < 7; i++) {
    document.querySelector(Class + "image" + i).style.display = "none";
    document.querySelector(Class + "image" + (i - 1)).style.display = "block";
  }
  if (i < 1) {
    document.querySelector(Class + "image7").style.display = "block";
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <img class="SAimage1" src="https://scontent.flhr4-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t31.0-8/26756508_1743696655674610_7179458580676129491_o.jpg?_nc_cat=0&oh=f16a2edf4ee735e66b6dab095b7fb43c&oe=5B6B32B3" alt="Tom Dining" style="display: block;">
  <img class="SAimage2" src="https://scontent.flhr4-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t31.0-8/26758659_1743696569007952_4447096103197624856_o.jpg?_nc_cat=0&oh=a7f015a6709fa9a26f06b07fe9782999&oe=5B6A180E" alt="Me Chilling" style="display: none;">
  <img class="SAimage3" src="https://scontent.flhr4-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t31.0-8/26678421_1743695449008064_7298258449829506874_o.jpg?_nc_cat=0&oh=d8fb71ad599a0a630f4d118c1d8be6ca&oe=5B6E0AFD" alt="The Road" style="display: none;">
  <img class="SAimage4" src="https://scontent.flhr4-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t31.0-8/26678110_1743696009008008_4042393389305650172_o.jpg?_nc_cat=0&oh=7d6afafd399c4a2d5d8f0747d59d8353&oe=5B73557C" alt="Night Van" style="display: none;">
  <img class="SAimage5" src="https://scontent.flhr4-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t31.0-8/26756324_1743697449007864_8430059194945119796_o.jpg?_nc_cat=0&oh=5c93856d22087dbf550fc98dfd7a79ce&oe=5B5FBF15" alt="" style="display: none;">
  <img class="SAimage6" src="https://scontent.flhr4-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t31.0-8/26678350_1743697612341181_2805503461338827658_o.jpg?_nc_cat=0&oh=1e6d3b0c44b783742de688cedacccc20&oe=5B6E31BF" alt="" style="display: none;">
  <img class="SAimage7" src="https://scontent.flhr4-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t31.0-8/26678350_1743697612341181_2805503461338827658_o.jpg?_nc_cat=0&oh=1e6d3b0c44b783742de688cedacccc20&oe=5B6E31BF" alt="" style="display: none;">
  <!-- Next/previous controls -->
  <button id="prev" onClick="imagePrev('SA')">&#10094;</button>
  <button id="next" onClick="imageNext('SA')">&#10095;</button>
</div>
```

i'm trying to create 2 separate functions that will hide the current image and show the next/previous one.  The functions have parameters which will hopefully allow them to act on different elements when called upon (i'm practicing making functions with broad scope and re-usability!).  I believe the problem is trying to combine the parameter Class with a string and integer i into a new class which will take the form "Classimage(number)".  What is the correct syntax when trying to form new strings form these parts?

Comment: `i` doesnt exist outside the `for` loop. But in any case please provide a [mcve] demonstrating your problem.

Comment: @Jamiec Actually it does, since it is not declared with `let`. It should be declared with `var`, though.

Comment: Your code should work just like that. Please show us your DOM/HTML and how you are calling these functions.

Comment: you should not use loop. it make no sense set  `display(i+1)` to  `block` then set it to `none` at next iteration

Comment: I understand that to select class you need it in .class format inside the querySelector method also right?

Comment: Yeah, the first problem is a class selector starts with `.` but there are more problems in your code than just that.

Comment: @apple apple Hi, can you explain why it doesn't make sense, when function is activated would it not be correct to hide ("none") current <img> and show ("block") the next?

Comment: no, it doesnt make sense. Think about it. First iteration of loop you hide index1 and show index 2, then you hide 2 and show 3, then hide 3 and show 4... etc.

Comment: Doh i see yes so if i remove the for loop, put `var i = 1` outside functions, then just before function curly brackets close put `i++` and `return i` that should work right?

Answer (score 0):

This can be simplified hugely. And there are a number of ways to achieve this - but keeping the code as close to your existing you can simply loop over all 7 possible images and either set it `block` or `none` depending on if it is the current image.

You'll need to keep track of what the "current" image is with a global variable.

```js
var currentImage = 1;

function updateImage(Class, selectedImage) {
  currentImage = selectedImage;
  for (var i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
    document.querySelector("." + Class + "image" + i).style.display = (i === selectedImage ? "block" : "none");
  }
}

function imageNext(Class) {
  var nextIndex = currentImage+1;
  if(nextIndex>7) nextIndex = 1;
  updateImage(Class, nextIndex)

}

function imagePrev(Class) {
 
  var nextIndex = currentImage-1;
  if(nextIndex<1) nextIndex = 7;
  updateImage(Class, nextIndex)

}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <img class="SAimage1" src="https://scontent.flhr4-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t31.0-8/26756508_1743696655674610_7179458580676129491_o.jpg?_nc_cat=0&oh=f16a2edf4ee735e66b6dab095b7fb43c&oe=5B6B32B3" alt="Tom Dining" style="display: block;">
  <img class="SAimage2" src="https://scontent.flhr4-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t31.0-8/26758659_1743696569007952_4447096103197624856_o.jpg?_nc_cat=0&oh=a7f015a6709fa9a26f06b07fe9782999&oe=5B6A180E" alt="Me Chilling" style="display: none;">
  <img class="SAimage3" src="https://scontent.flhr4-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t31.0-8/26678421_1743695449008064_7298258449829506874_o.jpg?_nc_cat=0&oh=d8fb71ad599a0a630f4d118c1d8be6ca&oe=5B6E0AFD" alt="The Road" style="display: none;">
  <img class="SAimage4" src="https://scontent.flhr4-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t31.0-8/26678110_1743696009008008_4042393389305650172_o.jpg?_nc_cat=0&oh=7d6afafd399c4a2d5d8f0747d59d8353&oe=5B73557C" alt="Night Van" style="display: none;">
  <img class="SAimage5" src="https://scontent.flhr4-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t31.0-8/26756324_1743697449007864_8430059194945119796_o.jpg?_nc_cat=0&oh=5c93856d22087dbf550fc98dfd7a79ce&oe=5B5FBF15" alt="" style="display: none;">
  <img class="SAimage6" src="https://scontent.flhr4-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t31.0-8/26678350_1743697612341181_2805503461338827658_o.jpg?_nc_cat=0&oh=1e6d3b0c44b783742de688cedacccc20&oe=5B6E31BF" alt="" style="display: none;">
  <img class="SAimage7" src="https://scontent.flhr4-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t31.0-8/26678350_1743697612341181_2805503461338827658_o.jpg?_nc_cat=0&oh=1e6d3b0c44b783742de688cedacccc20&oe=5B6E31BF" alt="" style="display: none;">
  <!-- Next/previous controls -->
  <button id="prev" onClick="imagePrev('SA')">&#10094;</button>
  <button id="next" onClick="imageNext('SA')">&#10095;</button>
</div>
```

If you want to make this more reusable, not require you to hardcode the length of the images, and not have a global variable for the current page, give them all the same class, and do it like the below.

```js
function imageNext(Class){
   var elems = document.querySelectorAll("." + Class);
   var index = Array.from(elems).findIndex(function(e){
      return e.style.display == "block";
   });
   var newIndex = index+1;
   if(newIndex == elems.length-1)
       newIndex = 0;
   elems[index].style.display = "none";
   elems[newIndex].style.display = "block";
}

function imagePrev(Class){
   var elems = document.querySelectorAll("." + Class);
   var index = Array.from(elems).findIndex(function(e){
      return e.style.display == "block";
   });
   var newIndex = index-1;
   if(newIndex == -1)
       newIndex = elems.length-1;
   elems[index].style.display = "none";
   elems[newIndex].style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <img class="SA" src="https://scontent.flhr4-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t31.0-8/26756508_1743696655674610_7179458580676129491_o.jpg?_nc_cat=0&oh=f16a2edf4ee735e66b6dab095b7fb43c&oe=5B6B32B3" alt="Tom Dining" style="display: block;">
  <img class="SA" src="https://scontent.flhr4-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t31.0-8/26758659_1743696569007952_4447096103197624856_o.jpg?_nc_cat=0&oh=a7f015a6709fa9a26f06b07fe9782999&oe=5B6A180E" alt="Me Chilling" style="display: none;">
  <img class="SA" src="https://scontent.flhr4-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t31.0-8/26678421_1743695449008064_7298258449829506874_o.jpg?_nc_cat=0&oh=d8fb71ad599a0a630f4d118c1d8be6ca&oe=5B6E0AFD" alt="The Road" style="display: none;">
  <img class="SA" src="https://scontent.flhr4-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t31.0-8/26678110_1743696009008008_4042393389305650172_o.jpg?_nc_cat=0&oh=7d6afafd399c4a2d5d8f0747d59d8353&oe=5B73557C" alt="Night Van" style="display: none;">
  <img class="SA" src="https://scontent.flhr4-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t31.0-8/26756324_1743697449007864_8430059194945119796_o.jpg?_nc_cat=0&oh=5c93856d22087dbf550fc98dfd7a79ce&oe=5B5FBF15" alt="" style="display: none;">
  <img class="SA" src="https://scontent.flhr4-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t31.0-8/26678350_1743697612341181_2805503461338827658_o.jpg?_nc_cat=0&oh=1e6d3b0c44b783742de688cedacccc20&oe=5B6E31BF" alt="" style="display: none;">
  <img class="SA" src="https://scontent.flhr4-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t31.0-8/26678350_1743697612341181_2805503461338827658_o.jpg?_nc_cat=0&oh=1e6d3b0c44b783742de688cedacccc20&oe=5B6E31BF" alt="" style="display: none;">
  <!-- Next/previous controls -->
  <button id="prev" onClick="imagePrev('SA')">&#10094;</button>
  <button id="next" onClick="imageNext('SA')">&#10095;</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Jamiec That great thanks, treating all elements of same class as an array seems sensible approach.  i follow your 2nd more reusuable version apart from the test function for findIndex, what is e in function(e)?  Thanks a lot that was very helpful :D

Comment: @LiamJones `e` is the element being iterated over.